# Probability of A given B given C

Tags: probability

How would I find P ((A|B)|C)? Do I substitute the formula for P (A|B), P=(A ∩ B))/(P (B)), and then redo the function to get (P (A ∩ B ∩ C))/(P (C)^2)?

I heard that P=(A|B ∩ C) can be used, but why would that be equivalent, unless you assume that C is independent of A?  Given a three-circle Venn diagram, the initial sample size would be too restricted.

Answer (score 6):

The notation $\mathsf P((A\mid B)\mid C)$ is not standard.   There should only be one bar between the event being measured and the condition.   When conditioning over two events, take the conjunction.

Both $\mathsf P(A\mid B, C)$ and $\mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C)$ mean the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$ and $C$.

$$\mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C) = \frac{\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C)}{\mathsf P(B\mid C)} = \frac {\mathsf P(A\cap B \cap C)}{\mathsf P(B\cap C)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $P((A|B)|C)=P(A|B\cap C)$  In both cases you are given that both $B$ and $C$ happened and asked for the probability of $A$ given that information.

Comment: Can you kindly show how this relation holds?

Comment: @q126y:  The Venn diagram argument is that the $|C$ restricts us to the area inside the $C$ circle.  The $|B$ restricts us to the $B\cap C$ lnes.  Then $P(A)$ under this assumption is the central rouleaux divided by the lens.